# Render Razor View To string not working with multiple PartialAsync inside PartialView in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

My method to render partial view to string:

```
        public static string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ITempDataDictionary tempData, ControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            var viewEngine = controllerContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;
            viewData.Model = model;
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {

                var viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, false);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View,
                    viewData, tempData, sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());
                viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext)
                    .Wait();
                var renderedView = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
                return renderedView;
            }
        }
```

This partial view renders without error:

```
@model News

@{
    var news = @Model;
}
@await Html.PartialAsync("SingleView", new SingleViewModel(news));
```

This partial view after RenderAsync returns empty string:

```
@model List<News>
@{ var newsList = Model; }
@foreach (var news in newsList)
{
    await Html.PartialAsync("SingleView", new SingleViewModel(news));
}
```

What's wrong?

RenderAsync must return rendered string instead of empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution, everything worked after replacing `Html.PartialAsync` with `Html.RenderAsync` in the foreach loop.

Found another solution, i should use razor syntax inside loop instead of c# code like this: `@await Html.PartialAsync("SingleView", new SingleViewModel(news));`.